# ArcGIS API for JavaScript Web Optimizer: 'Queued' forever

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Although ArcGIS web app optimizer behind the scenes uses the same dojo build system, it runs at least a twice slower. But the most unpleasant thing is it puts a building task in a queue with the “Your build has been queued and will start when resources become available. Feel free to close this browser tab; you'll receive an email when the build completes.” message. It seems that the queue never comes to an end. After the task gets status 'Queued', the next build task will have the same status, even the first one was canceled.
In such way it is impossible to create any build because of the queue.
I tried to create a build using ‘ArcGIS web app optimizer’ on Friday morning. The task was put to queue again. On Monday I have to cancel it because it was still in queue.
Then the ‘ArcGIS web app optimizer’ put in queue each build task I tried to create.  Further it was impossible to create any build by ‘ArcGIS web app optimizer’, even the simplest.

Please, help to figure out why the 'Queued' status appears and how to cancel it to create a new build.

Comment: Yes. I've had the same problem. Shortly after the Web Optimizer was released I was able generate a few builds successfully. Since then the jobs are queued indefinitely. I've given up and resorted to using this:

https://github.com/agrc/AGRCJavaScriptProjectBoilerPlate

Comment: Thank you for the example. I am able to create any build locally. Creating the build this way takes more efforts. It needs to download all the source packages.  
Therefore it seemed convenient to use ArcGIS Optimizer because it is easy and needs only source code of my application.

Answer (score 1):

awhile back someone else reported a similar problem that ended up being tied to a particular account.  can you reproduce the same behavior using different login credentials?

https://twitter.com/geogangster/status/558696890615607296

Comment: I am not allowed to register another account. I have only one, which can be used.